# "ita" used for "adeō"

Tags: vocabulary, grammar-choice

I'm reading Goffaux's 1823 Latin adaptation of *Robinson Crusoe* (it turns out there are FOUR nineteenth-century Latin adaptations of *Robinson Crusoe*!) and came across the sentence:

> Attamen propius **ita** dēmum subīit [scapha], ut iīs quī in nāvī essent fūnis prōjicerētur.

A page later comes

> Quidquid erat in oculīs spectantem **ita** dētinuit, ut, præteritī immemor, dē futūrō minimē cūrāret.

In both sentences I would have used *adeō* instead of *ita*.

Is *ita...ut* a common and/or correct construction where one would usually use *adeō*? Or is there a difference that I'm missing?

(I also believe that one could correctly use *tam* but that *adeō* is considered more proper? Would love thoughts on that, too.)

**EDIT**
C. M. Weimer says in the comments that all three are totally fine. Is there a difference in nuance here, or are they basically interchangeable?

Comment: All three are totally fine.

Comment: @cmw Well, that was easy enough. Thanks! Is there any difference in nuance between them, or period? Or they're really just interchangeable?

Comment: You could add a [link](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dadeo2) to a definition of adeo, for clarity. Sorry, I'm on the phone right now

Comment: FWIW, Ita... ut is attested in the VG, [Mt 5, 7](http://www.vatican.va/archive/bible/nova_vulgata/documents/nova-vulgata_nt_evang-lucam_lt.html#5)

Comment: Did you end up finishing this translation? I started reading Robinson Crusoe recently and by coincidence came across this post.

Comment: @cmw I did! I enjoyed it a lot. Are you reading in English or Latin?

Comment: English. I used a bit of it in my dissertation, and decided to go back and read it properly. Perhaps I'll do Latin afterwards. How was the Latin in it? Worth at least sampling?

Comment: Yeah. I went back to reread it a few months ago and found that my Latin had improved enough to the point at which I was noticing an error here and there but on the whole it's elegantly done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant Gildersleeve on consecutive sentences is section 551-552:

> Correlative demonstratives occur very often : **ita (sic), tam, tantopere, tanto, adeo, eo, huc ; talis, tantus, tot, is, eius modi,** and others of a similar meaning.

I haven't taken a close look, but it's difficult to hear a difference between *tam*, *adeo*, and *ita* when used as so. Once difference is that *ita* will have a force of "in such a way" more often than *tam* or *adeo* will, which instead mostly focus on degree.